# Trying to understand this Graph-DSL example (a simple FlowShape)

Tags: akka-stream

Given:

```scala
val merge = builder.add(Merge[Command](2))

msgToDomainCommand ~> merge.in(0)
domainCommand ~> merge.in(1)

merge ~> routeToSession

socket ~> eventToWebSocketsShape

// expose inlets/outlets
FlowShape(msgToDomainShape.in, eventToWebSocketsShape.out)
```

where

`msgToDomainCommand` is a `FlowShape`

`domainCommand` is a `PostOps`

`eventToWebSocketShape` is also a `FlowShape`

`routeToSession` is a `Sink`

and `socket` is a `Source`

What is this

```scala
socket ~> eventToWebSocketsShape
```

doing here?

I understand that `eventToWebSocketShape` is a `Flow`, which accepts values from the `socket` source, that's why they're plugged together:

`source ~> eventToWebSocketsShape`

But how would I model this in a graph? Would it look something like this then?

[image]

Which, to me, kind of doesn't make any sense. The whole `FlowShape`'s inlet doesn't flow all the way to the outlet; it goes to the sink.

But then we also have this Source (`socket`) floating around, which is then connected to the `FlowShape`'s outlet.

I'm very new to Akka Streams; just wanted to know if this is common.

`socket` will be an `ActorSource`, by the way.

Comment: The cool thing about Graph-DSL is that you can wire things however you want even if they don't make sense or they are not immediately obvious how they should work :). I believe you mapped the code to the diagram correctly. What seems to be the case is that some stuff happens out of this diagram. You said "socket" is an ActorSource. What happens in routeToSession? Perhaps the data that goes there emerges on the "socket"? Then you'd have your flow fully connected (implicitly). If that's the case it's a bit confusing how this is stiched together

Comment: hi @artur . thanks for confirming that this is indeed okay! yes, that's right! `routeToSession` is a Sink that has a reference to the `socket` Source. i materialize the `ActorSource` inside the graph to send it to `routeToSession`. (which is what this `domainCommand` is, it's a Command with a reference to the materialized `ActorSource`).

Comment: it's just confusing why spawn an `ActorSource` in the middle of nowhere; it's an WebSockets example, where bidirectional communication is needed. (communication from the user, and from the backend). but I don't see why the `ActorSource` there is needed. i'll tweak it a bit and see if I can make it better, thanks